# I am using hibernate 4.3.8 with swing application and getting org.hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, hibernate

Please suggest me a way to solve this issue.

*I didn't get this error in console application using single thread but when I used the same code in swing multi-thread application I got this exception.*

I am getting error at this code

```
Session session = HibernateUtilities.getSessionFactory().openSession();
```

This is the HibernateUtilities class

```
public class HibernateUtilities {

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

    private void createSessionFactory() {
        try {
            String configXmlPath = "hibernate/hibernate.cfg.xml";

            Configuration configuration = new Configuration()
                    .configure(configXmlPath);

            serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                    .applySettings(configuration.getProperties())
                    .build();

            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        if (sessionFactory == null) {
            new HibernateUtilities().createSessionFactory();
        }
        return sessionFactory;
    }

}
```

This is the config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306</property>
    <property name="hibernate.default_schema">school</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">demo</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>


    <mapping class="model.Student"/>
    <mapping class="model.Teacher"/>
    <mapping class="model.Course"/>

  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

CourseForm:

```
package view;

import hibernate.HibernateUtilities;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import model.Course;
import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;
import utilities.ButtonColumn;
import utilities.CourseTableModel;
import utilities.EmptyTextFieldException;

public class CourseForm extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private List<Course> courses;

    public CourseForm() {
        setCourses();
        initComponents();
        addActionListeners();
    }

    private void setCourses() {
        try {
            Session session = HibernateUtilities.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Course.class);
            courses = criteria.list();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void addActionListeners() {
        ButtonColumn buttonColumn = new ButtonColumn(coursesTable, null, 2);
        coursesTable.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
                JTable table = (JTable) me.getSource();
                Point p = me.getPoint();
                int rowIndex = table.rowAtPoint(p);
                if (me.getClickCount() > 0) {
                    if (table.columnAtPoint(p) == 2) {
                        deleteCourseInformation(rowIndex);
                    } else {
                        updateCourseInformation(rowIndex);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void deleteCourseInformation(int rowIndex) {
        String courseId = (String) coursesTable.getModel().getValueAt(rowIndex, 0);
        Session session = HibernateUtilities.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Course.class)
                .add(Restrictions.eq("id", courseId));
        Course courseToDelete = (Course) criteria.uniqueResult();
        session.delete(courseToDelete);
        session.getTransaction().commit();

        ((CourseTableModel) coursesTable.getModel()).removeRow(rowIndex);
    }

    private void updateCourseInformation(int rowIndex) {
        String courseTitle = (String) coursesTable.getValueAt(rowIndex, 1);
        courseTitleField.setText(courseTitle);

        String courseId = (String) coursesTable.getValueAt(rowIndex, 0);
        courseIdField.setText(courseId);
        courseIdField.setEditable(false);

        addButton.setText("Update");
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        courseTitleField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        coursesTable = new javax.swing.JTable();
        addButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        courseIdField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        resetButton = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel3.setText("Course Title:");

        courseTitleField.setName("Course Title"); // NOI18N

        coursesTable.setModel(new CourseTableModel(courses, new String[] {"ID","Title", "Delete"}));
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(coursesTable);

        addButton.setText("Add");
        addButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                addButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel5.setText("Course Information:");

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setText("All Courses:");

        courseIdField.setName("Course ID"); // NOI18N

        jLabel4.setText("Course ID:");

        resetButton.setText("Reset");
        resetButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                resetButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(jLabel5)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jLabel4)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(courseIdField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 153, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jLabel3)
                            .addGap(32, 32, 32)
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addComponent(resetButton)
                                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                    .addComponent(addButton))
                                .addComponent(courseTitleField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 153, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(21, 21, 21)
                .addComponent(jLabel5)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4)
                    .addComponent(courseIdField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                    .addComponent(courseTitleField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(16, 16, 16)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(addButton)
                    .addComponent(resetButton))
                .addGap(33, 33, 33)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 332, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private String getTextFieldValue(JTextField textField) throws EmptyTextFieldException {
        String value = textField.getText().trim();

        if (value == null || value.isEmpty()) {
            throw new EmptyTextFieldException(textField.getName());
        }

        return value;
    }

    private void addButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        try {
            String courseId = getTextFieldValue(courseIdField);
            String courseTitle = getTextFieldValue(courseTitleField);

            Course course = new Course();
            course.setId(courseId);
            course.setName(courseTitle);

            if (addButton.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Add")) {
                Session session = HibernateUtilities.getSessionFactory().openSession();
                session.beginTransaction();               
                session.saveOrUpdate(course);
                session.getTransaction().commit();

                ((CourseTableModel) coursesTable.getModel()).addRow(course);
            } else if (addButton.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Update")) {
                Session session = HibernateUtilities.getSessionFactory().openSession();
                session.beginTransaction();
                session.saveOrUpdate(course);
                Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Course.class);
                courses = criteria.list();
                session.getTransaction().commit();

                ((CourseTableModel) coursesTable.getModel()).setCourses(courses);
            }
        } catch (EmptyTextFieldException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, ex.getMessage());
        }
    }                                         

    private void resetButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        courseIdField.setText("");
        courseIdField.setEditable(true);
        courseTitleField.setText("");
        addButton.setText("Add");
    }                                           

    public static void display() {
        new CourseForm().setVisible(true);
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton addButton;
    private javax.swing.JTextField courseIdField;
    private javax.swing.JTextField courseTitleField;
    private javax.swing.JTable coursesTable;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JButton resetButton;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Traceback:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:201)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getJdbcConnectionAccess(AbstractSessionImpl.java:341)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.<init>(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionCoordinatorImpl.<init>(TransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.<init>(SessionImpl.java:258)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl$SessionBuilderImpl.openSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1589)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.openSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:999)
    at controller.Repository.save(Repository.java:45)
    at view.CourseForm.addButtonActionPerformed(CourseForm.java:202)
    at view.CourseForm.access$200(CourseForm.java:16)
    at view.CourseForm$2.actionPerformed(CourseForm.java:108)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:702)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:700)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:699)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect a race condition in multi threading since you said it is working well in single threaded console application.

```
public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    synchronized(HibernateUtilities.class) {
        if (sessionFactory == null) {
            new HibernateUtilities().createSessionFactory();
        }
    }
    return sessionFactory;
}
```

You might need to synchronize access to `sessionFactory` as multiple threads can invoke it at the same time and create multiple instances.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but I am afraid that it didn't help. I am still getting the exception. Is there any other thing I can do to try fixing the problem.

Comment: You are not closing your hibernate sessions. you must call session.close();